# wp_get_attachment_metadata returns false with add_action() 'add_attachment' hook

Tags: actions

With the following code in functions.php - `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` returns false and or empty. Perhaps I am attempting to use `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` before it's ready? As some tests have shown when manually add a previously added `$attachement_ID` I get the desired information..

```
function my_custom_attachment($attachment_ID) {

  $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment_id); // returns false

}

add_action('add_attachment', 'my_custom_attachment');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add_attachment` runs right after an attachment is added to the DB, but but before the metadata is generated. If you don't need the value to be in the database yet, you can use the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` filter to hook in. However, if you need the data to be in the database already, you'll have to use `updated_post_meta` and check that the `meta_key` passed in equals `_wp_attachment_metadata`.

Comment: Awesome - just had a chance to test it and it worked. Thank You!