# Automatically Add Specified Value to Attachment Metadata upon Upload

Tags: functions, actions

I am trying to create a function that automatically adds a value to the attachment metadata (if it matters, on Audio uploads).

For example, I want to add a value of 'artist' and output it as my own specificity (for the sake of the example, just simply 'test')

I've tried numerous things but each one, thus far, has not worked (and outputs an unspecified error upon uploading the media).

Here's a couple things I've tried:

```
function auto_update_audio_meta($post_ID) {
add_post_meta( $post_ID, 'artist', 'test');
}
add_action('add_post_meta', 'auto_update_audio_meta');
```

I've also tried hooking to `update_post_metadata`, and variations such as

```
function auto_update_audio_meta() {
wp_update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'artist', 'test');
}
add_action('update_post_metadata', 'auto_update_audio_meta', 10, 5);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See also https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30666/add-custom-field-to-image-editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close! Try using these hooks instead.

```
// Add post meta to new audio uploads.
function auto_update_audio_meta( $post_ID ) {
  if ( wp_attachment_is( 'audio', $post_ID ) ) {
    add_post_meta( $post_ID, 'artist', 'test' );
  }
}
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'auto_update_audio_meta' );
```

For attachment updates

```
// Update post meta to updated audio uploads.
function auto_update_audio_meta( $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before ) {
  if ( wp_attachment_is( 'audio', $post_ID ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'artist', 'test' );
  }
}
add_action( 'attachment_updated', 'auto_update_audio_meta', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and edits.   I tried your first code, checked the backend details, and also used `get_post_meta` on the attachment to see an array of it's values.  `artist` was not listed. Hooking to `add_attachment` was the first thing I tried, and had since moved past it since I did not think it was the appropriate hook because it fires before metadata is generated.  See the first answer at : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61519/wp-get-attachment-metadata-returns-false-with-add-action-add-attachment-hook

Comment: The reason why I chose `update_post_metadata` was after reading the top answer in this thread : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16835/how-to-hook-update-post-meta-and-delete-post-meta - but I could not get it to work.  Also it is important to note that I am not looking to GET the attachment metadata, only add a value to it, so I'm not sure exactly where this could be hooked onto..

Comment: Err--- actually nevermind, it worked, thanks!  It just wasn't appearing where I was expecting it. I was looking for it to be in `_wp_attachment_metadata` with all the other metadata?  Instead it's in the `_wp_attached_file` array which includes the url and my new added value.  Anyways, I will kindly accept your answer :)

Comment: Glad it worked out. I made a few edits so you might've used the broken code first.